# Nested Loop Unrolling in C

Tags: c, for-loop, loop-unrolling

I want to optimize my code by using unrolling loop. I tried to apply unrolling but I think I cannot do it and I cannot see my problem. I want to apply unrolling loop to outer loop.

This loops do transpose of matrix.

*This is my loop to apply unrolling loop:*

```
void transpose(int dim, int *src, int *dst) {
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
            dst[j * dim + i] = src[i * dim + j];
}
```

This is my unrolling loop:

```
void transpose(int dim, int *src, int *dst) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, dimi = 0, dimj = 0, tempi = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < dim; i += 8) {
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            dimj = j * dim + i;
            dimi = i * dim + j;
            dst[dimj] = src[dimi];

            tempi = i + 1;
            if (tempi < dim) {
                dimj = j * dim + tempi;
                dimi = tempi * dim + j;
                dst[dimj] = src[dimi];

                tempi += 1;
                if (tempi < dim) {
                    dimj = j * dim + tempi;
                    dimi = tempi * dim + j;
                    dst[dimj] = src[dimi];

                    tempi += 1;
                    if (tempi < dim) {
                        dimj = j * dim + tempi;
                        dimi = tempi * dim + j;
                        dst[dimj] = src[dimi];

                        tempi += 1;
                        if (tempi < dim) {
                            dimj = j * dim + tempi;
                            dimi = tempi * dim + j;
                            dst[dimj] = src[dimi];

                            tempi += 1;
                            if (tempi < dim) {
                                dimj = j * dim + tempi;
                                dimi = tempi * dim + j;
                                dst[dimj] = src[dimi];

                                tempi += 1;
                                if (tempi < dim) {
                                    dimj = j * dim + tempi;
                                    dimi = tempi * dim + j;
                                    dst[dimj] = src[dimi];

                                    tempi += 1;
                                    if (tempi < dim) {
                                        dimj = j * dim + tempi;
                                        dimi = tempi * dim + j;
                                        dst[dimj] = src[dimi];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop unrolling as an optimization is best left to the compilers.

Comment: Loop unrolling is a job for the compiler, let it do it for you.

Comment: The compiler can see if this has other side effects, such as a worse cache hit. Are you taking that into account as well?

Comment: Yeah I know, @Chad I have to optimize myself because I have to use this function in my homework. :( Can you optimize it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm taking it. I have to optimize myself because I have to use this function in my homework. @RadLexus

Comment: Okay, fair reason. When you say "I tried to apply unrolling", what makes you think it did not work? That part is missing from your question.

Comment: For each optimization operation, our speedup point increase, but I implemented above and this point did not increase, also it decreased. I think I cannot do unrolling loop. I mean my implementation is wrong. Can you see any error in my implementation above? @RadLexus

Comment: I solved it. This is true unrolling loop btw. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the error in your current code is but here is another approach.

```
void transpose(int dim, int *src, int *dst) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= dim-8; i += 8)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
        {
                dst[j * dim + (i+0)] = src[(i+0) * dim + j];
                dst[j * dim + (i+1)] = src[(i+1) * dim + j];
                dst[j * dim + (i+2)] = src[(i+2) * dim + j];
                dst[j * dim + (i+3)] = src[(i+3) * dim + j];
                dst[j * dim + (i+4)] = src[(i+4) * dim + j];
                dst[j * dim + (i+5)] = src[(i+5) * dim + j];
                dst[j * dim + (i+6)] = src[(i+6) * dim + j];
                dst[j * dim + (i+7)] = src[(i+7) * dim + j];
        }
    }

    // Use the normal loop for any remaining elements   
    for (; i < dim; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
            dst[j * dim + i] = src[i * dim + j];
}
```

Notice: The number of multiplication can be reduced by introducing a variable like:

```
int jdim = j * dim + i;
dst[jdim + 0] = ...
dst[jdim + 1] = ...
...
dst[jdim + 7] = ...
```

and likewise for the RHS.

Comment: Thanks. This code is faster than my code with 0.3 times. :)

Comment: @SevkiBekir: this code might be faster just because of the order of reads and writes. Try swapping the `i` and the `j` loop in the naive function and benchmark that too.

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of unrolling loops is to remove tests. You make no assumptions on the value of `dim`, so you need to keep all the tests.  I doubt you will see any improvement with the unrolled code, but only careful benchmarking can tell you for a given compiler and architecture if it makes a difference.

One thing for sure: it made the code much more difficult to read and much easier to mess up.

If you know the most common values for `dim`, you can try and optimize those.  For example if you know the most common case is 3x3 matrices, you could write this:

```
void transpose(int dim, const int *src, int *dst) {
    if (dim == 3) {
        dst[0 * 3 + 0] = src[0 * 3 + 0];
        dst[0 * 3 + 1] = src[1 * 3 + 0];
        dst[0 * 3 + 2] = src[2 * 3 + 0];
        dst[1 * 3 + 0] = src[0 * 3 + 1];
        dst[1 * 3 + 1] = src[1 * 3 + 1];
        dst[1 * 3 + 2] = src[2 * 3 + 1];
        dst[2 * 3 + 0] = src[0 * 3 + 2];
        dst[2 * 3 + 1] = src[1 * 3 + 2];
        dst[2 * 3 + 2] = src[2 * 3 + 2];
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
                dst[j * dim + i] = src[i * dim + j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Modern compilers are good at optimizing the simple original code, taking advantage of hardware specific capabilities for vectorization. Unless you know exactly what to optimize and when, they will do a much better job than you could, without risking spurious bugs.

Comment: Not just the compiler. The processors often have special instructions which make loops faster than the equivalent code written linearly.

Comment: Thank you! @chqrlie

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an unrolled loop. Notice that the goal is to remove conditional statements and dependencies on variables. Also, this code has not been tested.

```
void transpose(int dim, int *src, int *dst) {
    // represent where the data is being read and where it is going
    int dstIndex = 0;
    int srcIndex = 0;

    // precalculate constants used within the loop
    int total = dim*dim;
    int unrolled = dim / 4;

    int dimx0 = dim*0;
    int dimx1 = dim*1;
    int dimx2 = dim*2;
    int dimx3 = dim*3;
    int dimx4 = dim*4;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    // since the matrix is being transposed i,j order doesn't matter as much
    // because one of the matrices will be accessed by column and the other
    // will be accessed by row (more effecient)
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < unrolled; i++) {
            // here the loop is being unrolled
            // notice that each statement does not rely on previous statements
            // and there is no conditional code
            dst[dstIndex + 0] = src[srcIndex + dimx0];
            dst[dstIndex + 1] = src[srcIndex + dimx1];
            dst[dstIndex + 2] = src[srcIndex + dimx2];
            dst[dstIndex + 3] = src[srcIndex + dimx3];
            dstIndex += 4;
            srcIndex += dimx4;
        }

        // the transpose was previously completed in larger blocks of 4
        // here whtever indices that were not transposed will be taken care of
        // e.g. if the matrix was 13x13, the above loop would run 3 times per row
        // and this loop would run once per row
        for (i = unrolled; i < dim; i++) {
            dst[dstIndex] = src[srcIndex];
            dstIndex += 1;
            srcIndex += dim;
        }

        // increment the source index
        srcIndex %= total;
        srcIndex += 1;
    }
}
```